# How to retrieve the all Projects under Rally workspace?

Tags: extjs, rally, code-rally

I want to know is it possible to retrieve the all projects under workspace in rally. If yes how to retrieve them?

We are building a Rally custom HTML dashboard using Rally sdk2.1, we need show all projects list in the dashboard.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  There is a project picker component that will let your navigate the project hierarchy and select a project.  Otherwise you could probably just add a custom list of type project to your dashboard...

Comment: @kyle thanks for reply, i just want to show the  list of projects in my custom dashboard.Is their way to do it ?
ex:
projectId  projectName  projectStatus GITHUb Link Jenkins Link
12345 TESTproject open  github url     jenkins          build url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just add a Custom List app to your dashboard from the app catalog.  Then just edit the settings, choose project as the type, and then you can choose all the fields you'd like to display using the field picker.

Comment: thanks for reply ,can we do it using custom html interface as i need to customize my own columns?

Comment: I might start with this example and just switch it to use projects... https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/example/custom-data-grid

Comment: above example will give me userstories under one project, but i need all the projects under workspace with customizeable columns that will include my own custom columns like GIThub link ,jenkins link etc.basically i need the custom dashboard table of 3 columns 
projectName,projectGithubLink,projectJenkisLink

Comment: Right.  Like I said above, you need to edit the example and change it from loading user stories to projects instead.  Then in that example you can see it is calculating some custom data and also shows how to have a custom renderer for a column.  it should be straightforward to update to your use case...